# Django rest keep getting AssertionError: 'ListCreateAPIView' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building new app using Django rest and have this issue. I've searched on web, no solution or workaround was found.

Here is the view.py code below of the serializer

I've tried both overriding get_queryset() method and setting queryset variable, but no result

views.py

```
class GoodListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):

    authentication_classes = (authentication.BasicAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    serializer_class = GoodModelSerializer
    queryset = Good.objects.all()
```

I want to list all goods related to the user, but unfortunately there is an error.If you need some additional code or smth, just ask

Comment: The error is not for GoodListCreateAPIView, but for ListCreateAPIView. Have you used that class directly in your URLs?

Comment: @DanielRoseman maaaaaaan. Thank you! That was horrible mistake